# 'RUSAGE_THREAD' was not declared in this scope

Tags: compiler-errors

I am trying to build a C++ program using Android ndk 7 through terminal using makefile and get this error message.

```
'RUSAGE_THREAD' was not declared in this scope
```

'RUSAGE_THREAD' use -

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
```

which is also included in the file.
Can anybody help me to figure out this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
#define __USE_GNU /* required before including  resource.h */

#include <sys/resource.h>
```

This should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem, and had to define `_GNU_SOURCE` above the inclusion of `<sys/resource.h>` :

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sys/resource.h>
```

I know I'm several years late, but hopefully this will help someone.